# Most efficient way to compare two lists and delete the same

Tags: c#, list, compare, .net-4.5

I want to compare two lists and get the valid words into a new list.

```
var words = new List<string>();
var badWords = new List<string>();

//this is just an example list. actual list does contain 700 records
words.Add("Apple");
words.Add("Moron");
words.Add("Seafood");
words.Add("Cars");
words.Add("Chicken");
words.Add("Twat");
words.Add("Watch");
words.Add("Android");
words.Add("c-sharp");
words.Add("Fool");

badWords.Add("Idiot");
badWords.Add("Retarded");
badWords.Add("Twat");
badWords.Add("Fool");
badWords.Add("Moron");
```

I am looking for most efficient way to compare the lists and put all the 'good' words into a new list. The finalList shouldn't contain "Moron", "Twat" and "Fool".

```
var finalList = new List<string>();
```

Or is it unnecessary to create a new List? I am happy to hear your ideas!

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"most efficient"_ do you mean "time" or perhaps "memory usage" or a combination of both or something else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Comment: @MickyD I meant time. Sorry, I should have asked more accurately

Comment: `list1.Enumerable.Except(list2)` will return all the elements in `list1` that are not in `list2`. See [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Enumerable`[Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) function storing in `System.Linq` namespace

```
finalList = words.Except(badWords).ToList();
```

Most efficient way to save your time and also the fastest way to do it, because `Except` implementation uses `Set`, which is fast

Comment: ...and excecution time. This uses a set to store all items. It will run in O(n+m). I don't think that there will be a faster way of doing this.

Comment: I would definitely go with this approach. However, depending on the size of the lists, there may be faster approaches. For small lists, like the ones given, a simple loop might be faster. I strongly suspect the actual problem has much longer lists though, which makes this solution the best.

Comment: Just so you know - Your link to the msdn is in Russian.

Comment: @KonstantinZadiran No worries - +1'd for a clean answer

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
List<string> cleanList = words.Except(badWords).ToList();
```

This is efficient because `Except` uses a set based approach.

An even more efficient approach is to avoid that "bad" words are added to the first list at all. For example by using a [`HashSet<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) with a case-insensitive comparer:

```
var badWords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase){ "Idiot", "Retarded", "Twat", "Fool", "Moron" };

string word = "idiot";
if (!badWords.Contains(word))
    words.Add(word);
```

Comment: Thank you for explained answer. I will definitely take your approach with Hashset<> in consideration

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx

```
var words = new List<string>();
var badWords = new List<string>();

//this is just an example list. actual list does contain 700 records
words.Add("Apple");
words.Add("Moron");
words.Add("Seafood");
words.Add("Cars");
words.Add("Chicken");
words.Add("Twat");
words.Add("Watch");
words.Add("Android");
words.Add("c-sharp");
words.Add("Fool");

badWords.Add("Idiot");
badWords.Add("Retarded");
badWords.Add("Twat");
badWords.Add("Fool");
badWords.Add("Moron");

var result = words.Except(badWords).ToList();
```

Edit: Got in late.

Answer (score 1):

you can use contains method

```
words.Where(g=>!badWords.Contains(g)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your don't want to create a new `List` you can remove the bad words from your existing `List` with [`RemoveAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
words.RemoveAll(badWords.Contains);
```